# How to change the condition of a gridview cell based on drop down list selection in the same row

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to change the condition of a asp.net gridview cell based on drop down list selection in the same row so
in row 1 if column1 = yes column2,column3,column4,column5 = 1
row 2 if column1 = No column2,column3,column4,column5 = 0

Comment: Does the gv have a drop down now, and are you setting and filling out the dll for each row. Or, is this just a column in the gv that was set by some other page and that dll? So, first issue before changing the dll choice, is do you have the dll filling out correctly for that given row. Since without this first part, then your current question of changing what displays on the gv row comes AFTER we have that dll filled out correctly for each row. For each row of the GV, you will have to load up the dll choices, AND THEN set the dll to the correct value for that row. Then your above question.

Comment: so, perhpas your question is two parts. The first part is to fill out the ddl correctly with the list of choices. You THEN have to set the ddl to the correct current row value. Then and ONLY then are we to deal with your above question of changing the ddl value. But, we can't deal with your current question until we are sure part 1 of filling out the dll with choices, and then setting the dll to the current row value is first done. Once this step one is achieved, then we can move on your question of changing the the color or visible of the other cells on that row. So, step 1 has to be achieved